# How to set ships randomly using pygame

Tags: python, while-loop

I want to set ships like in image using pygame.
However I got coordinates only from #right(in long for loop).

How can I fix this?

```
for i in range(1,6):
    while True:
        x,y = random.randrange(14,24,1),random.randrange(1,11,1)
        angle = ship_angle[random.randrange(0,4,1)]
        X,Y = x+i*math.cos(angle),y+i*math.sin(angle)
        
        if  (14 <= X <= 24) and (1 <= Y <= 11) and (not((X,Y) in ai_ships)):
            #down
            if (x == X) and (y < Y):
                for d in range(i):
                    ai_ships.add((x*TILE,(y+d)*TILE))
                break
            #up
            if (x == X) and (y > Y):
                for d in range(i):
                    ai_ships.add((x*TILE,(y-d)*TILE))
                break
            #right
            if (y == Y) and (x < X):
                for d in range(i):
                    ai_ships.add(((x+d)*TILE,y*TILE))
                break
            #left
            if (y == Y) and (x > X):
                for d in range(i):
                    ai_ships.add(((x-d)*TILE,y*TILE))
                break
              
        else:
            continue
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the only problem, but [`math.cos(), sin()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.cos) uses radians, so you want to use, for example:

```
angle = math.radians(ship_angle[random.randrange(0,4,1)])
      # ^^^^^^^^^^^^ Add this
X,Y = x+i*math.cos(angle),y+i*math.sin(angle)
```

This will convert your degrees to radians before calling the `sin()` and `cos()` functions.